# SqlBulkCopy - Save Data

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, sqlbulkcopy

I got some weird error that append randomly.
Here is the error :
An error occurred while preparing the adjusted curves: Unable to convert the supplied Decimal value for the data source to the date type of the specified target column

The weird thing is, something everything work fine and something this error happen.

The system calculate a lot of data and at this end save this data using bulckCopy

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
{
    bulkInsert.BulkCopyTimeout = Settings.Default.CommandTimeout;              
    EnumerableExtensions.ForEach(_curveAdjustmentHistoricColumnMappings, mapping =>  bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add(mapping));
    bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = TABLE_CURVE_ADJUSTMENT_HISTORIC;
    var dataTable = adjustedCurve.ConvertTo(true);
    bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dataTable);
    dataTable.Clear();
}
```

Here is the model of the data we saving

```
public class CurveAdjustmentHistoricEntity : BaseCoreEntity
{
[PrimaryID]
public int CurveAdjustmentHistoricId { get; set; }
        public int CurveAdjustmentId { get; set ; }
        public DateTime SessionDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public decimal PreviousValue { get; set; }
        public decimal ForwardValue { get; set; }
        public decimal HistoricalShock { get; set; }
        public decimal Percentile { get; set; }
        public int CurveTermId { get; set; }
        public decimal ShockAdjustment { get; set; }
        public decimal AdjustedValue { get; set; }
        [ReadOnly]
        public CurveAdjustmentAuditEntity Audit { get; private set; }
}
```

Does anyone ever encounter that problem ?

Thank

Comment: Had you checked the connection timeout value? I mean, the problem may be focused not over the reported problem but in other cause, like SQL connection timeout...

Comment: Can you show us the schema for the table you are trying to save into?

Comment: Maybe I think datatype is not mapped. Show structure of the table in DB.